# add/delete numerical values in list box guide of MATLAB using push button and update it using push button

Tags: matlab

I need to add/delete numerical values presented in the list box of MATLAB guide after selecting the  number of values by the user. Also i need to  update the listbox values using push button pressed

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your opening function, before the line guidata(hObject, figure1), you should have some variable to keep track of your numbers. Declare something like

```
handles.numbers = {};
```

In general, if you have a cell array, cell_array, you can set the listbox like this. In the call back for your push button, first update the cell array and then load it into your list box using this line

```
set(handles.tag_of_listbox, 'String', handles.numbers, 'Value', 1);
```